# How do I distribute points on faces based on face angle?

Tags: geometry-nodes, faces, normals

I'm trying to distribute points on a terraced object but keeping them only on the "floor" faces and not on the "wall" faces. In this case I'm trying to make a teraced city with scattered buildings which should only be distributed to the ground and not the walls. Is this possible, for example using the normals node and calculating what angle the face normals have? Any help would be much appreciated, I feel like there has to be an easy solution that im just not seeing.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case the node `Compare` will help you.

If you set it to *Vector* and *Dot Product* and compare the normals of the faces with the vector $(0,0,1)$ (pointing up), you will get a selection that contains only the faces pointing up.

You can then use this selection directly in the node `Distribute Points on Faces`.

[image]

Comment: +1 I'm so glad I'm slow... I would have given an answer with the _Dot Product_ calculated by a _Vector Math_ node... I didn't know the _Compare_ node has this function (I don't use it very often, and most of the time for floats).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes, you are right: This function is well hidden, and one would actually expect it under "Vector" ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much, worked just as intended.